# Why does str() round up floats?

Tags: python, string, rounding

The built-in Python str() function outputs some weird results when passing in floats with many decimals. This is what happens:

```
>>> str(19.9999999999999999)
>>> '20.0'
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
>>> '19.9999999999999999'
```

Does anyone know why? and maybe workaround it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It's not `str()` that rounds, it's the fact that you're using floats in the first place. Float types are fast, but have limited precision; in other words, they are *imprecise by design*. This applies to all programming languages. For more details on float quirks, please read "[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)"

If you want to store <s>and operate on</s> precise numbers, use the `decimal` module:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> str(Decimal('19.9999999999999999'))
'19.9999999999999999'
```

Comment: -1 `Decimal` also has limited precision (28 decimal digits by default). It's NOT a magic cure-all. See my updated answer.

Comment: That's true, Decimal types can only *store* precise numbers, operating on them will truncate them.

Comment: `str` _also_ rounds (compare `0.9999999999999999` and `str(0.9999999999999999)` in REPL. This can be avoided with `repr` (although it won't help with rounding due to float imprecision).

Answer (score 6):

A float has 32 bits (in C at least). One of those bits is allocated for the sign, a few allocated for the mantissa, and a few allocated for the exponent. You can't fit every single decimal to an infinite number of digits into 32 bits. Therefore floating point numbers are heavily based on rounding.

If you try `str(19.998)`, it will probably give you something at least close to 19.998 because 32 bits have enough precision to estimate that, but something like 19.999999999999999 is too precise to estimate in 32 bits, so it rounds to the nearest possible value, which happens to be 20.

Comment: Entirely correct, except that Python's `float` is C `double`, usually 64 bits.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that this is a problem of understanding floating point (fixed-length) numbers. Most languages do exactly (or very similar to) what Python does.

Python `float` is [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) 64-bit binary floating point. It is limited to 53 bits of precision i.e. slightly less than 16 decimal digits of precision. `19.9999999999999999` contains 18 decimal digits; it cannot be represented exactly as a `float`. `float("19.9999999999999999")` produces the nearest floating point value, which happens to be the same as `float("20.0")`.

```
>>> float("19.9999999999999999") == float("20.0")
True
```

If by "many decimals" you mean "many digits after the decimal point", please be aware that the same "weird" results happen when there are many decimal digits *before* the decimal point:

```
>>> float("199999999999999999")
2e+17
```

If you want the full `float` precision, don't use str(), use repr():

```
>>> x = 1. / 3.
>>> str(x)
'0.333333333333'
>>> str(x).count('3')
12
>>> repr(x)
'0.3333333333333333'
>>> repr(x).count('3')
16
>>>
```

**Update** It's interesting how often `decimal` is prescribed as a cure-all for float-induced astonishment. This is often accompanied by simple examples like `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 != 0.3`. Nobody stops to point out that `decimal` has its share of deficiencies e.g.

```
>>> (1.0 / 3.0) * 3.0
1.0
>>> (Decimal('1.0') / Decimal('3.0'))  * Decimal('3.0')
Decimal('0.9999999999999999999999999999')
>>>
```

True, `float` is limited to 53 binary digits of precision. By default, `decimal` is *limited* to 28 decimal digits of precision.

```
>>> Decimal(2) / Decimal(3)
Decimal('0.6666666666666666666666666667')
>>>
```

You can change the *limit*, but it's still *limited* precision. You still need to know the characteristics of the number format to use it effectively without "astonishing" results, and the extra precision is bought by slower operation (unless you use the 3rd-party `cdecimal` module).

Answer (score 1):

For any given binary floating point number, there is an infinite set of decimal fractions that, on input, round to that number.  Python's `str` goes to some trouble to produce the *shortest* decimal fraction from this set; see GLS's paper http://kurtstephens.com/files/p372-steele.pdf for the general algorithm (IIRC they use a refinement that avoids arbitrary-precision math in most cases).  You happened to input a decimal fraction that rounds to a float (IEEE double) whose shortest possible decimal fraction is not the same as the one you entered.

Comment: (1) "fraction" is irrelevant; it happens with very large integers too. It's repr() that produces the shortest representation, not str(), and it's only recent; repr() used to use 17 decimal digits of precision.