# converting strings to numeric

Tags: python

What's a simple way to convert stings into numerics:
from:

```
['3.65e+03', '1.14e+04', '1.35e+04', '1.46e+04']
```

to:

```
[3.65e+03, 1.14e+04, 1.35e+04, 1.46e+04]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I hope you are aware of the [limitations](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) in representing the floating point accurately in our current architectures.

The simple way for conversion is simply this.

```
>>> s = ['3.65e+03', '1.14e+04', '1.35e+04', '1.46e+04']
>>> map(float,s) 
>>> [3650.0, 11400.0, 13500.0, 14600.0]
```

But float rounds them off to the nearest value and it's representation does not matter as long as values are same. Sometimes, those values can have near-equal representation with same value (almost) for e.g.

```
>>> s = ['3.65e+93', '1.14e+04', '1.35e+04', '1.46e+04']
>>> map(float,s)
[3.6500000000000001e+93, 11400.0, 13500.0, 14600.0]
```

Update - Please see John Machin's comment for this behavior/repr.

But if you want exact representation, for e.g. if you are dealing calculations involving money, then you may want to use the `Decimal` type instead of float, which for all purposes can behave in the same way as your float.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> map(Decimal,s)
[Decimal('3.65E+93'), Decimal('1.14E+4'), Decimal('1.35E+4'), Decimal('1.46E+4')]
```

Comment: -1 You are confused: `float()` ALWAYS rounds to the nearest `float` value, if necessary. "As you saw"?? There is NO ROUNDOFF involved in your first `map()` output. In your second, `3.6500000000000001e+93` is merely an artifact of your use of a pre-2.7 Python, where `repr()` always used 17 decimal digits of precision. Python 2.7 produces `3.65e+93`. In ANY Python, `3.6500000000000001e+93 == 3.65e+93` is true. Very shaky grounds for introducing `decimal` which has its own limited precision.

Comment: John - Thanks for the explanation and correction. I have updated few sections in my answer. As for Decimal's precision, it is controllable using `getcontext().prec =n` isn't it?

Comment: Yes the decimal precision is controllable; there are lots of knobs/buttons/switches that the novice can turn/push/flip. Your answer is still confused. (1) delete "(almost)" (2) If decimal behaves the same as float, why use it?

Answer (score 4):

```
map(float, your_list)
```

or

```
[float(x) for x in your_list]
```

**Update** For an explanation of why an unqualified recommendation to "use decimal" is not a good idea, see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683869/why-does-str-round-up-floats/5696968#5696968).

Comment: +1 for the list comprehension -- usually more common in Python, plus allows an `if` clause when required. BTW, did you intend to link to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683869/why-does-str-round-up-floats/5696968#5696968)?

Answer (score -1):

```
numbers = [eval(s) for s in ['3.65e+03', '1.14e+04', '1.35e+04', '1.46e+04']]
```

eval's a bit of a hack, but it's pretty well guaranteed to work. (specific float is also a good approach.)

Comment: -1: Presumably the strings are coming from an external source (command line, file, network etc). Blindly using ``eval()`` is a huge risk as it allows arbitrary code to be executed. Even discounting this security risk, why would you want to use ``eval()`` over the in-built ``float()`` function which was designed specifically for this purpose?