# Why is my string function [str()] working incorrectly?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to print the nth term of a string, but beyond a certain term this doesn't work.

I set up my number to be such that the 2nd term is 2, 3rd term is 3 etc. 16th term is 6. This all works correctly up until term 17, where a number 8 is printed which doesn't make any sense. Strangely, this is working correctly for the first 16 terms but the 17th it gets wrong. When I try to print the 18th term, I get an error saying the string index is out of range, which it clearly isn't.

```
print(str(0.2345678901234567890)[17])
```

Interestingly, if I go with the notation:

```
 print("0.2345678901234567890"[17])
```

then it works perfectly well with every element being printed correctly.
Hence I believe there is something wrong with the str() function, but I can't find anything online.

Comment: `str` is not an alternate syntax for writing string literals; it is not supposed to be equivalent to sticking quotation marks around a piece of source code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does str() round up floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683869/why-does-str-round-up-floats)

Comment: @kabanus: That's part of the issue, but another part (arguably a bigger part) seems to be that the questioner is expecting `"stuff"` and `str(stuff)` to be equivalent.

Comment: @kabanus: It wouldn't fit on that question.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure where I got this idea from but I was convinced that the two are the same thing. Given that I'm working within a function and I can't just use     "number", what is the next best way to easily convert my digits to a string? (number here is a variable, but doing "number" will literally give me the string with letters of number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the results of appying `str()` :

```
>>> str(0.2345678901234567890)
'0.234567890123'
```

it rounds up the number, and there are not enough digits to get #17.

Comment: If you look closer, you'll see that this is not rounding up. Python rounds 0.2345678901234567890 to the nearest value representable as a float, and `str` rounds *that* to the shortest decimal representation that round-trips to the same float when converted back to a float.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. I didn't guess to write this. Could you take a look at my other comment on this thread about how to correctly convert to a string within a function?

Comment: @TimofeyAbramski your problem is not in conversion to string. your problem is that the numbers you write cannot be represented using `float` in python -- last two digits will be lost. `print '%.20f' % 0.2345678901234567890` results in 
`0.23456789012345680145` -- note, there no '9' after '8'... the number is already truncated when being converted to `float`.

Comment: @lenik are you saying i shouldn't be using floats here, but something else instead? sorry, not sure what I should do to resolve this issue

Comment: @TimofeyAbramski for the integers, python automatically converts things into the long numbers, representing the number with plenty of digits (hundreds and, possibly, thousands). for the floating points, there's `float32` and `float64` which can hold only so many digits. if you need higher precision, you ought to choose your own representation format, which can contain all required info and is easy enough to handle.